# Запись огромного архива на несколько флешек

Tags: usb, резервное-копирование, архивация

Есть 150Г сжатый архив и есть 10 USB-ФЛЕШЕК по 15Г. Как записать архив на USB-ФЛЕШКИ так, что бы без проблем перенести архив, если что на другую машину.

Comment: Нарубить кусочками и записать. Например командой split (в linux)

Comment: Флешка не очень надежный носитель, поэтому для архивов ее лучше не использовать, скорее она всегда была предназначена для временного накопления и переноса данных. В вашем случае (в \*nix) для перемещения частей огромного файла на флешки я бы использовал [dd](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dd)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самый простой вариант в Total Commander

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]